# How to Add a Cutom Task Form to a Visual Studio 2010 Sharepoint State Machine Workflow

Tags: 2010, form

I have developed a SharePoint 2010 state machine workflow in Visual Studio 2010 for a document library. I have built a custom task list and a custom content type for the tasks. The workflow itself works fine. But it is using the default task forms, which I actually don't have a problem with except that there are fields on the form that the users don't need to see or fill out. I would like to customize the task forms but I'm not sure what the best way is to do that.

I've been struggling with this for about a week. I've found how-to's and tutorials (including Robert Shelton's) on using InfoPath forms and application pages, and I haven't been able to get anything to work; either I can't deploy it because of enigmatic errors or I can deploy it but the workflow errors out (with one of those "Error Occurred" because it apparently can't create the task. I'm kind of new to this VS workflow development too, which doesn't help! :)

Do you have any recommendation as to which is the best method using SP/VS 2010? And if you have a recommendation, can you point me to a good step-by-step site? I don't want anything complicated, just to be able to exclude some fields that are on the default form, and maybe one calculated field. Is designing an aspx page in SPD an option?